# Constraints changed when modifying UIViewController.frame

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, constraints, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` which I add to another `UIViewController` as a child. When the child gets added, the parent set frame on my child using `childVC.frame = ....`, but this fubars my constraints.

I can duplicate this issue in IB easily. Create a `UIViewController`, change the size to be "Freeform" and ditch the status bar (just so it looks right visually). Add in a `UIButton` (or anything) and constraints so so they are both the same size (see image below)
[image]

Now change the size of the top level view in the view controller and watch what happens.
[image]

It changed my constraints on me. I wanted my button to just get bigger and still hold the original constraints. Something which happens automatically if you toggle between iPhone retina 3.5/4.0 in screen or change from landscape to portrait. But why not when I resize the view? This is making a royal pain to lay things out in freeform and test different sizes.

More importantly... why does the exact same thing happen when I set the `frame` in code when I add the child for my VC and how do I prevent it?

Comment: My only comment on IB is that IB's constraints editing is crap - bit you're not "reproducing" the issue by doing that. In an Autolayout world, you'd never `setFrame:` - everything is constraints based. So you should be editing the constraints that apply to your child view control let's view, not setting its frame.

Comment: I just want some way in IB to say "my `superview` will be width/height" and have it re-display with the existing constraints. Next I'm going to try mucking in the XML file. Maybe if I modify my view controller width/height values there it will leave my constraints untouched. Probably not, but worth a test.

Comment: Have you tried just dragging the superview to the size you want? Don't set the frame.

Comment: I have, it changes the constraints rather than re-applying the existing constraints to the new new size.

Answer (score 1):

Frame based calculations and Auto Layout are not compatible. Or at least, they mean stormy waters. That's why you are having issues. Having switched to Auto Layout you have to accept that you no longer manipulate `frame` directly.

So, you cannot do `childVC.frame = whatever`.

Instead, you must now use Auto Layout to update the size of `childVC.frame`. Do that by creating - in IB - an `IBOutlet` that is the width constraint of `childVC`. Similarly, create another `IBOutlet` that is the `childVC` height constraint.

In your view controller, update the `constant` value to change the size.

```
myWidthConstraint.constant = 123.f;
```

The place to do this is in the controller's `updateViewConstraints` method, or in the case of a view, `updateConstraints`.

That said, it's better to set up Auto Layout so that you don't need any programmatic updates. When properly defined, it will know how to handle things with the view's bounds change. To be honest, it should only be necessary to update sizes programmatically if you want to do something more unusual.

Can I just say however that you are better